# CSS classes conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `input` field and a `button`. On clicking the `button`, it will be checked that whether `input` field has some data or not. If there is no data, then the `input` field will be highlighted. On focus of on the `input` field, error message will be shown. On `keyup` event, the `input` will no longer be highlighted, but the error message will remain.

Below is the code that I have tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btnclick').click(function(){
       if($('[name="tName"]').val() == "")
        {
         $('[name="tName"]').addClass('validationInput');
            $('[name="tName"]').closest('div').addClass('wrap');
        }
        else
          alert('Success');
      });
  
      $('[name="tName"]').on('focus', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('validationInput')) {
            $(this).next("span.vspan").html("Please enter Name");
            $(this).next("span.vspan").css("display", "inline-block"); 
        }
        });
  
       $('[name="tName"]').on('keyup', function () {
        $(this).removeClass("validationInput");
        $(this).closest('div').removeClass("wrap");
        });
    });
```

```css
.validationInput,
    .validationInput:focus,
    .validationInput:hover {
        background-color: #FFFFE0!important;
        border: 1px solid red!important;
        height: 30px
    }

    .wrap>span {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%
    }

    .wrap>span:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        right: -5px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: red;
        border-style: solid;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFE0
    }

    input[type=text].vtooltips {
      position: relative;
      display: inline;
    }
    input[type=text].vtooltips + span.vspan {
      position: absolute;
      display:none;
      font-size:12px; 
      font-family: Arial; 
      color:white;
      border-radius:3px; 
      background: #DC000C;
      width:50%;
      border: 1px solid #6D6D6D;
      line-height: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #AFB1B1;
      margin-left:5px;
      line-height:15px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <span>
        <input class="mandatoryText vtooltips form-control textbox" style="width: 100%;vertical-align:top;border-radius:4px;" maxlength="100" name="tName" type="text">
        <span class="vspan"></span> 
      </span>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input id="btnclick" value="Click" type="button">
```

Here is a [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/YY1JFaLbCJ) of the same.

But, the CSS is conflicting in some manner. The error message shall be shown on `focus` event, but it is shown after the `keyup` event is fired. This happens because of `wrap` class (found out after lots of analysis), but I do not know why this happens. What have I done wrong?
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/2aillUhFwH

Comment: @Banzay: This is not the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Hi add below code inside your button click event,

`$('[name="tName"]').focus();`

and also change `<span>` tags to `<div>` tags like in snippet.

Then whole code looks like below,

```
$('#btnclick').click(function(){
        if($('[name="tName"]').val() == "")
        {
            $('[name="tName"]').addClass('validationInput');
            $('[name="tName"]').closest('div').addClass('wrap');
            $('[name="tName"]').focus()
        }
        else
          alert('Success');
      });
```

Code snippet,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btnclick').click(function(){
       if($('[name="tName"]').val() == "")
        {
         $('[name="tName"]').addClass('validationInput');
            $('[name="tName"]').closest('div').addClass('wrap');
            $('[name="tName"]').focus();
        }
        else
          alert('Success');
      });
  
      $('[name="tName"]').on('focus', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('validationInput')) {
           $(this).next("span.vspan").css("display", "inline-block").html("Please enter Name");
           
        }
        });
  
       $('[name="tName"]').on('keyup', function () {
        $(this).removeClass("validationInput");
        $(this).closest('div').removeClass("wrap");
        });
    });
```

```css
.validationInput,
    .validationInput:focus,
    .validationInput:hover {
        background-color: #FFFFE0!important;
        border: 1px solid red!important;
        height: 30px
    }

    .wrap>span:first {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%
    }

    .wrap>span:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        right: -5px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: red;
        border-style: solid;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFE0
    }

    input[type=text].vtooltips {
      position: relative;
      display: inline;
    }
    input[type=text].vtooltips + span.vspan {
      position: absolute;
      display:none;
      font-size:12px; 
      font-family: Arial; 
      color:white;
      border-radius:3px; 
      background: #DC000C;
      width:50%;
      border: 1px solid #6D6D6D;
      line-height: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #AFB1B1;
      margin-left:5px;
      line-height:15px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    
      <span class="caret">
       
        <input class="mandatoryText vtooltips form-control textbox" style="width: 100%;vertical-align:top;border-radius:4px;" maxlength="100" name="tName" type="text">
        <span class="vspan"></span> 
       
      </span>
      
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input id="btnclick" value="Click" type="button">
```

Comment: No, it does not work. On `focus` event the error message should be displayed, which instead is being displayed after `keyup` event is fired.

Comment: check the edited code.. You should change the `<span>` as well.

Comment: In my snippet, you can see there is a small triangle on top of the textbox when it is highlighted, which is why I have used `span` instead of `div`. In your snippet, the triangle is missing.

Comment: Yes please. That will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you. I just did make a function to add and remove the css class and display or not  the message:

```js
jQuery.fn.myValidate = function(){
  if(this.val() == ""){
    this.next("span.vspan").html("Please enter Name");
    this.next("span.vspan").css("display", "inline-block");
    this.addClass('validationInput');
    this.closest('div').addClass('wrap');
    return false;
  }else{
    this.next("span.vspan").css("display", "none");
    this.closest('div').removeClass("wrap");
    this.removeClass('validationInput');
    this.next("span.vspan").css("display", "none");
    return true;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnclick').click(function(){
    if ($('[name="tName"]').myValidate())
      alert('Success');
  });
  
  $('[name="tName"]').on('focusout keyup', function (evt) {
    $(this).myValidate();
  });

});
```

```css
.validationInput,
    .validationInput{
        background-color: #FFFFE0;
        border: 1px solid red;
        outline: none;
        height: 30px
    }

    .wrap>span {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%
    }

    .wrap>span:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        right: -5px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: red;
        border-style: solid;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFFFE0
    }

    input[type=text].vtooltips {
      position: relative;
      display: inline;
    }
    input[type=text].vtooltips + span.vspan {
      position: absolute;
      display:none;
      font-size:12px; 
      font-family: Arial; 
      color:white;
      border-radius:3px; 
      background: #DC000C;
      width:50%;
      border: 1px solid #6D6D6D;
      line-height: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #AFB1B1;
      margin-left:5px;
      line-height:15px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <span>
        <input class="mandatoryText vtooltips form-control textbox" style="width: 100%;vertical-align:top;border-radius:4px;" maxlength="100" name="tName" type="text">
        <span class="vspan"></span> 
      </span>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input id="btnclick" value="Click" type="button">
```

Comment: I removed overflow: hidden from CSS, do not make sense to me If the goal is to show them. And I changed hover validationInput in CSS by focusout in Jquery.

Comment: It is still not the desired output.